# Is it correct/acceptable to have two FK pointing to the same table?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Is it correct/acceptable to have two FK pointing to the same table?

In this business logic, a message can only be sent from one user to another.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    age TINYINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE message (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    content VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    from_user_id INT NOT NULL,
    to_user_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(from_user_id) REFERENCES user(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(to_user_id) REFERENCES user(id)
);
```

[image]

Comment: looks sane to me.

Comment: Yes, this is very common.